# TCP/IP MTU confused

Tags: tcp, mtu

My friend's network quality is very good. It is normal to request most websites, but for individual websites.

I guess it is slow (even unable to open the page) mainly because of TCP retransmission.

I guess TCP retransmission is due to too large MTU.

Am i right？ but why PC set so large MTU?

Here are the pictures, sorry in Chinese.

[wireshark tcp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8DwL.jpg)

[ping failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LUYU.png)

[ping success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzAGU.png)

[MTU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZ9Wl.png)

Comment: The web server did not acknowledge the segment that the client sent. Hence, the client retransmitted it up to *n* retries before it closed the connection. There's nothing wrong with the client's MTU. The server isn't responding. You need to investigate why. Did the client's data actually reach the server? A server-side capture would help.

Comment: @Rafael thanks, but I think the retransmission is due to the TCP packet discarded by the intermediate node. As the picture,  when the data is larger than 1464, the ping will not work.

Comment: yes, DF=1, This should be set by Chrome itself

Comment: It sounds like there is a misconfigured link somewhere in the path to 111.13.29.225. Without knowing your network, I guess it's your uplink. Your ethernet interface's MTU and uplink ethernet interface's MTU should match. Otherwise, the uplink device may silently drop oversized frames (giants). Try changing your ethernet interface's MTU to 1492 and setting the MSS to 1452. Also, are you on DSL? An MTU of 1492 is generally associated with PPPoE. If so, you'll need to configure your system accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

Your Loopback pseudo-interface has an unusually big MTU.

AFAIS, the destination of the highlighted packet is your TP-link modem. The Source MAC address could not be identified. It generally shows the brand of your ethernet card, so it most probably is this strange Loopback device.

The problem you are facing does not seem to happen because of an unusually big MTU, I suspect this pseudo-interface is buggy, or it just blocks the website you are trying to connect to.

Disable/Uninstall this pseudo-interface and try again...

Comment: thanks, but The actual network interface uses "以太网", and the mtu is 1500 as picture.

Comment: @yongzhang: In the images you sent, there is no problem caused by MTU size. And you should have seen the brand of the ethernet card on Wireshark. What are the MAC addresses of both interfaces? By looking at them, you would understand which interface was in use...